# The size of SkiaSharp rectangle is smaller than on iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I draw list items with position x, y, width and height by SkiaSharp. This is ok in Android but layout and size items is smaller in iOS. Please view bellow code and image to know:

In Xaml:

```xml
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White">
            <Grid Padding="20">
                <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvasView" 
                               PaintSurface="SKCanvasView_PaintSurface" BackgroundColor="Beige"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

In View:

```cs
    private void SKCanvasView_PaintSurface(object sender, SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int NumberColums = 10;
            int NumberRows = 9;
            Size m_CurrentTableSize = new Size();
    
            canvasView.WidthRequest = this.Width; //width of page
            canvasView.HeightRequest = this.Height;//height of page
    
            var canvas = e.Surface.Canvas;
            var widthView = Width;
            var heightView = Height;
            m_CurrentTableSize = new Size(widthView / NumberColums, heightView / NumberRows);
    
            ObservableCollection<Table> Tables = _viewModel.Tables;
    
            for (int i = 0; i < Tables.Count; i++)
            {
                Table tableModel = Tables[i];
    
                int row = tableModel.PositionY;
                int col = tableModel.PositionX;
    
                int height = tableModel.Height;
                int width = tableModel.Width;
    
                var dH = (float)m_CurrentTableSize.Height / 68;
                var dW = (float)m_CurrentTableSize.Width / 68;
    
                row = (int)(dH * (float)row);
                col = (int)(dW * (float)col);
    
                height = (int)(height * dH);
                width = (int)(width * dW);
    
                var minSize = Math.Min(height, width);
    
                tableModel.Height = (int)minSize;
                tableModel.Width = (int)minSize;
    
                canvas.DrawRoundRect(new SKRoundRect(new SKRect((float)col, (float)row, (float)col + (float)tableModel.Height, (float)row + (float)tableModel.Width)), GetColor(tableModel.Status));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

In Android show normal:

[image]

In iOS, layout not full:

[image]

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Since your code is incomplete we can't reproduce the issue , could you provide the viewmodel code? Besides, I see you divide `68` on the variable `dH` , maybe the hard-coded number causes the problem .

Answer (score 0):

Try making it FillAndExpand for the grid. Like this

```xml
<Grid Padding="20" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
```